# one to many relationship without using foreign key in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, iqueryable

I have model class of student

```
public class student
{
   // here I have a collection of subjects, for which I don't want to use foreign key
   public int Id{ get; set; }
   public virtual Collection<Course> Course { get; set; }
}
```

and i have a class with course

```
public class course
{
   public int Id{ get; set; }
   public int studentId{ get; set; }
   public virtual students student{ get; set; }
}
```

Here is the problem when I am getting the data of students in students class Course data getting `null` value by using repository pattern

```cs
studentservice.Getstudents<student>().ToList();
public IQueryable<T> Getstudents<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null) where T : student 
{ 
    var query = studentRepository.FindAll().OfType<T>();
    if (predicate != null) query = query.Where(predicate);
    return query;
}
```

Comment: Please show us your query

Comment: studentservice.Getstudents<student>().ToList();
in student service


public IQueryable<T> Getstudents<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null) where T : student
        {
            var query = studentRepository.FindAll().OfType<T>();
            if (predicate != null)
                query = query.Where(predicate);
            return query;

        }

Comment: Edit your question please. Code in comments is illegible. And what do you mean by "without using foreign key"? `Course` (the class) has a FK `studentid`. BTW, I think a 1:n association isn't appropriate here. If each course only has one student this is going to be a very expensive school!